# Is it possible to prevent a modal from hiding if it's visibility prop rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component with four different lists of items. An item is placed in a list depending on the date. When the user clicks a button to change the date of that item a modal appears with a date picker (the item's dateModalVisbility prop switches to true). This works as expected but then if an item's date change causes it to switch lists, the date picker modal disappears without the prop switching to false. Then when you click the button to reopen it switches to false and then after another press switches back to true and reopens. I believe this is caused by the rerender of the item when it switches into a different list.

I would like to force the modal to stay open even when it switches lists. I have tried making the different lists functions that I call before anything else renders but this did not solve the issue. I am out of ideas and unsure if this is even possible to do.

My flatlists (this.props.todos comes from redux):

```
<FlatList
  data={_.sortBy(this.props.todos, item => {
    return item.date;
  })}
  extraData={this.props.todos}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    if (moment().isSame(item.date, 'day')) {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          todoItem={item}
          deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
        />
      );
    }
  }}
/>
<View style={styles.headerViewStyle}>
  <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle}>Tomorrow</Text>
</View>

<FlatList
  data={_.sortBy(this.props.todos, item => {
    return item.date;
  })}
  extraData={this.props.todos}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    if (
      moment()
        .add(1, 'day')
        .isSame(item.date, 'day')
    ) {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          todoItem={item}
          deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
        />
      );
    }
  }}
/>

<View style={styles.headerViewStyle}>
  <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle}>Upcoming</Text>
</View>

<FlatList
  data={_.sortBy(this.props.todos, item => {
    return item.date;
  })}
  extraData={this.props.todos}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    if (
      moment()
        .add(1, 'day')
        .isBefore(item.date, 'day')
    ) {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          todoItem={item}
          deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
        />
      );
    }
  }}
/>

<View style={styles.headerViewStyle}>
  <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle}>Sometime</Text>
</View>

<FlatList
  data={_.sortBy(this.props.todos, item => {
    return item.date;
  })}
  extraData={this.props.todos}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    if (moment().isAfter(item.date, 'day') || item.date === null) {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          todoItem={item}
          deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
        />
      );
    }
  }}
/>
```

The todoItem component:

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;

    return (
      <View>
        <ItemSwipeRow item={todoItem} completeItem={this.props.deleteTodo}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.props.toggleItemMenu(todoItem)}
            underlayColor={null}>
            <ListItem
              containerStyle={styles.todoItem}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.contentStyle}
              title={todoItem.text}
              titleStyle={{ color: '#FCEFEF', fontSize: 16 }}
              rightElement={todoItem.date ? this.renderDate.bind(this)() : null}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </ItemSwipeRow>
        {todoItem.itemMenuToggled ? <ItemMenuBar item={todoItem} /> : null}
        {this.props.reminderToggleActive && todoItem.date ? (
          <ReminderToggleButtons item={todoItem} />
        ) : null}
        <NotesModal item={todoItem} />
        {todoItem.dateModalVisible ? <DatePickerModal item={todoItem} /> : null}
      </View> //this line above is responsible for displaying the date picker modal
    );
  }
}
```

And the DatePickerModal:

```
class DatePickerModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal transparent animationType="fade" visible>
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                <Feather
                  name="x-square"
                  size={35}
                  color={'#db5461'}
                  onPress={() => this.props.toggleDateModal(this.props.item)}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
              {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
                <IosDatePicker item={this.props.item} />
              ) : (
                <AndroidDatePicker />
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

I can provide the actions and button that opens the item but I don't think that's where the issue is coming from. The button/actions are doing their job right.

Comment: Would it make sense to block the re-render while the modal is open? Then when the modal is closed allow the re-render. It would cause the list to not update until the modal is closed, but if that is ok then probably. Your best bet. (using componentedShouldUpdate lifecycle method).

Comment: Interesting, I will look into it and let you know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: My only question, since the modal visibility prop is within each item and the componentShouldUpdate will be in the flatlist, wouldn't I have to check every element in the list to see if any of their visibility elements are true to prevent the update?

Comment: Or I could make a global variable true every time it opens and use that instead? And make it false when the modal closes?

Comment: What I would do... instead of each item having a modal for itself... Instead have one modal that you render on the component that contains the list and then the items will just manipulate the modal via props. This way you don't have multiple modals to handle rendering. Just 1 top level modal that changes content.

Comment: Added an example in my answer. Obviously not complete and probably won't run, but this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-arrange the way you are using the modal. Instead of each component having a modal add one modal to the top level component and then use props to set the items that was selected. Somthing like this:

```js
export default class TopComponent extends React.Component {

  this.state = {
    selectedItem: null,
    modalvisible: false,
  }
  
  render = () => {
    return (
    <FlatList renderItem={({item, key} => (<MyItem onItemSelected={item => this.setState({ selectedItem: item, modalVisible: true}))} />} />
    <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
      <Text>this.state.selectedItem</Text>
    </Modal>
  }

}
```

Here is a quick codesandbox to show some more details: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-6518p

Comment: does it need to be on the top level? It would be much easier if I could do it within each item since the button to trigger the modal is within each item.

Comment: You can simply pass a property (like onItemSelected in my example) that the button calls in order to trigger the modal. Obviously you can keep it in the renderItem, but that is what is causing you issues right now. The items are re-rendering when the list changes which kills the modal. If the modal is higher up then that won't happen.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I have the list, and then the render item. Inside of each item, there is a swipe row component that contains the button they would press to trigger the modal. How could I use the onItemSelected to pass that through and make the modal visible with the right item when that button is hit in the grandchild? Sorry, that's the one part I don't really get how I would do.

Comment: I added a codesandbox to show what I mean with some more detail.

Comment: I am getting an error that the onSelected prop being passed down is not a function, I will post the code showing what I did in an edit.

Comment: I don't think it's going to work actually. Part of the issue I was having before is that the props weren't being passed down right. Now in the modal it is being buggy.